# I sell 100 shares of XYZ at loss on June 30th. Then I sell a put on XYZ on July 15th (OTM) expiring in August 19th. Is it a wash sale?

Tags: stocks

I sold 100 shares of XYZ on June 30th. Then i sold the put on the same equity on July 15th. The put option expires on Aug 19th. Is it a wash sale if the option is exercised or not exercised?
Please explain.

Comment: Tip: Tax questions need a country tag.

Answer (score 1):

If the put is exercised before July 30th (30 days after the sale), then it would likely be considered a wash sale since you bought the same security back within 30 days.

But two things come to mind:

- Options are rarely exercised before expiry - it is usually advantageous to sell the option rather than exercise early.
- The effect of the wash sale is that the loss is carried forward to the bought position, meaning that the cost basis of the original 100 shares is used for the bought shares.

The second point means that the loss is not *lost*, but at worst it's *deferred*. If the bought shares are sold within the same tax year then the effect is the same (other than the paperwork of declaring the wash sale). If the shares are sold in a different tax year the loss is deferred to the year in which they're sold.